# TypeScript doesn't check return type when use generic

Tags: typescript

say we have the following code :

```
class Foo<T> {
  lift<R>(): Foo<R> {
    const bar = new Foo<T>()
    return bar
  }
}
```

why there is no error? `Foo<T>` and `Foo<R>` may be different type.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNA3gKGtEAlgGYAuSASmgBQCUAXHIhRjnnsPAHYQnQBGYAE7QAvNE4BTAO6Nk6WrjaCJJAK6DO-IYoC%202HUA)

Comment: My guess is that because typescript checks by its shape, not by definition. Since T and R extends from same type, TS doesn't make error.

Comment: "T and R extends from same type", what is the same type you mean ? and even when invoking the method you specify the different type, still no error . like ```const foo = new Foo<string>()   foo.lift<number>()```

Comment: Both T and R can receive all types so they treated as same type. Also, from the point of view of creating instance, `T` doesn't constraints function definition. If you add `R extends T` on function generic, you will get error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TS uses structural type matching and not nominal. This means that 2 types are compatible if their structure is compatible.

You can read about how matching happens for generics [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#generics).

The reason your example works is that from a structure point of view there isn't anything that differentiates between `Foo<string>` or `Foo<number>` for instance. This is gonna work in TS

`const a: Foo<string> = new Foo<number>()`

This is also the reason why your function works, because `Foo<TypeA>` is compatible with `Foo<TypeB>` for **any** `TypeA` and `TypeB`.

If you add anything else that use `T` then the structural compatibility is broken and you get the error you are expecting:

```
class Foo<T> {
  field: T | null = null

  lift<R>(): Foo<R> {
    const bar = new Foo<T>()
    return bar
  }
}
```

```
Type 'Foo<T>' is not assignable to type 'Foo<R>'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.
    'R' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T'.(2322)
```

You can see this in action [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNA3gKGtAZgJYCmIAJgFzQrQA+0AdgK4gjQC8jLI2u0IhfABckAJTQAKAJRUEycVj55g8BhCHQARmABOHRsQDucRKklSl0HcSFMdDLbr4BfbK+wq1GsLNPqdhAwA5hicDEYmyPCaAFbEwELm2EA)